# rank leaderboard in mongo with surrounding players

Tags: mongodb

how would I create a query to get both the current player's rank and the surrounding player ranks.  For example, if I had a leaderboard collection with name and points

```
{name: 'John', pts: 123}
```

If John was in 23rd place, I would want to show the names of users in the 22nd and 24th place as well.

I could query for a count of leader board items with pts greater than 123 to get John's rank, but how can I efficiently get the one player that is ranked just above and below the current player?  Can I get items based on index position alone?

I suppose I can make 2 queries, first to get the number the rank position of a user, then a skip limit query, but that seems inefficient and doesn't seem to have an efficient use of the index

```
db.leaderboards.find({pts:{$gt:123}}).count();
-> 23

db.leaderboards.find().skip(21).limit(3)
```

The last query seems to scan across 24 records using the its index, is there a way I can reasonably do this with a range query or something more efficient?  I can see this becoming an issue if the user is very low ranked, like 50,000th place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to do three queries:

```
var john = db.players.findOne({name: 'John'})
var next_player = db.players.find(
    {_id: {$ne: john._id}, pts: {$gte: john.pts}}).sort({pts:1,name:1}).limit(-1)[0]
var previous_player = db.players.find(
    {_id: {$ne: john._id}, pts: {$lte: john.pts}}).sort({pts:-1,name:-1}).limit(-1)[0]
```

Create indexes on name and pts.

Comment: Thanks, how do you make sure it's the adjacent record and not just any record that is greater or less than.. since I didn't see a sort on it.  Also, I tried looking at the query execution  with explain() and it doesn't seem to work with findOne.  How can I look at the index that it's using.

Comment: colleciton.find({ ... query ... }).limit(-1).explain() is equivalent to explaining a findOne().

Comment: so in the next_player query, how do I ensure that it's the next adjacent rank rather than just any rank that's higher than the current player?

Answer (score 0):

Answer of **A. Jesse Jiryu Davis** is ok but I think there is another better option where geo/2d index could be used.

You could start with creating **2d index** on **pts** field. And query the N number of documents near to a given point or a score. For example if you want to fetch 10 documents with points near to a score let say 123 then you can do this:

```
db.players.find( { pts: { $near: [ 123, 123 ] } } ).limit(10)
```

Points probably need to be normalised to fit the 2d index coordinates but this should work.