# Querying for a user relative leaderboard with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of users, each user has a points attribute (see schema below).

My end goal is to return a sorted array of limited documents according to a specific user location, or in other words, a small part of a leaderboard relative for a specific user location.

Currently I query and sort all users, find the user I want in the returned array and slice the array according to that. I was wondering if there is a query that will save me returning all users.

Sample User Schema:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "points" : 5852 ,
    "key" : "user1"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "points" : 3835,
    "key" : "user2"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "points" : 1984,
    "key" : "user3"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
    "points" : 2437,
    "key" : "user4"
}
```

Lets assume I want the query to return 3 documents sorted by points - 
The document of "user4" (my relative user), the document after him in the leaderboard ("user3" in the example above) and 1 document before him ("user2" in the above example)

Thanks!

**Edit:** Im using mongoose as well if this simplifies things.

**Edit2:** Please see below the expected output -

```
 /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
        "points" : 3835,
        "key" : "user2"
    }
/* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
        "points" : 2437,
        "key" : "user4"
    }
 /* 3 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
        "points" : 1984,
        "key" : "user3"
    }
```

Note that "user1" does not appear in the output as the query asks for 1 user ranked above and 1 user ranked below "user4"

Comment: `user4-user3-user-2`? this is not sorted by "points"

Comment: Its quite confusing about your expected output. Can you please add expected output in question?

Comment: @Vishwas , thanks for the feedback. I've added the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to do this: [rank leaderboard in mongo with surrounding players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992750/rank-leaderboard-in-mongo-with-surrounding-players)

As it says in the answer to that question, the easiest way to do it is with three queries. Even though that's an increase in the number of queries, the data you transfer will be significantly reduced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As the linked post is 3 years old I think its worth asking if there is a better way to do this (with one query will be optimal). Also, why is above solution better than my solution? (return all users sorted and slice according to user position).

Comment: In general, processing the data in place (i.e. on the server) rather than transferring it all to the client and processing it there is better as it cuts down the amount of data needing to be transferred. Also, the server (Mongo in this case) has probably been heavily optimized to manipulate the data and query it, so it makes sense to use it!